# Choosing prepositions for writing between and within region disparities

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions, british-english

We are working on an methodology, allowing to detect disparities between the regions and within/inside the regions. For example:

- There is a two-fold difference in salary **between region** A and B -
  this is a between region disparity.
- Only 2% of residents receive a median salary in region C and 70% in region D - this is a **within/inside region** disparity.

**Does the following sentence, using words *between* and *within* carry the same message:**

> Novel methodology for identifying **between** and **within** region disparities in income

Or should I use other words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use the prepositions *between* and *within* as adjectives. I would suggest going with Latin prefixes here, using ***inter-regional*** and ***intra-regional***:

> Novel methodology for identifying inter- and intra-regional disparities in income

The words do actually mean *between* and *within* and provide useful combined forms.

If you re-order your title, you can use *between* and *within*:

> Novel methodology for identifying disparities in income between and within regions

Comment: Spot on. For once, the Latin does the job better than most English circumlocution.